# Using ellipse for Cauchy integral.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently working on a homework problem where I need to evaluate the following:

$\int_{\gamma}(z^2+2iz)^{-1} dz$ where $\gamma(t) = 2\cos t+i \sin t, 0\le t\le 2\pi$

I was thinking of using the local Cauchy Theorem, but that involves open disks. Is there a similar theorem that uses open ellipses? More curious than looking for a way to evaluate the integral (although advice is welcome).

Update: $\int_{\gamma}(z^2+2iz)^{-1}dz = \pi$ is what I found for evaluating the integral.

Comment: Your evaluation is correct. Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

Write
$${1\over z^2+2iz}={i\over2}\left({1\over z}-{1\over z+2i}\right)\ .$$
To the second part you can apply Cauchy's theorem since the pole is far away from the ellipse. As for the first part, you should be familiar with the fact that
$$\int_\gamma{1\over z}\>dz=2\pi i$$
for any curve $\gamma$ going once around the origin.

Comment: thank you very much for the advice. This is the approach I took for evaluating the integral.